# PHP - Update Displayed Info Upon Changing PDF Canvas

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've been running into an issue while trying to update a script for a client. I'm still somewhat new to the industry, so I wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything.

I am attempting to edit a web page which displays a number of PDFs in canvas views. The issue arises when a user tries to switch which PDF they're viewing. The function that retrieves the PDFs has a setTimeout in place to get the content to reload every minute, as the PDFs themselves are updated with new data every 5 minutes and the users need to be able to monitor the data as it comes in. However, when switching from one PDF canvas to the next, I found that the PDF doesn't update. The only PDF that reloads and updates is the one whose canvas has been open. This is what I'm trying to change. I want the PDF display to update not only every minute, but also whenever a user switches which PDF they're viewing.

What this told me is that I need to add something that loads the PDFs again when switching canvas views. First, I tried taking the function that updates the PDFs and calling it whenever the user switches the canvas view. This seemed to work, but the issue ended up changing. The page would begin to reload more and more often the more times you would change canvas views - I'd assume because the setTimeout within the function had then been called more than once.

My second attempt was to make a new function that simply didn't have the setTimeout code and call that instead. I must have done something wrong however, because after calling that function in the code, none of the PDFs wanted to load at all.

I'll paste the code for the functions I need to work with below. Any help is appreciated, especially if I'm just missing something obvious. If you need any other details, let me know. Thank you to anybody who offers help.

```
function getReport(reportName, frameId) {
    var params = {
      report: reportName
    };
    $.post('/getReport.php', params, function(data){
      if (data == "") {
        window.location.href="/login.php";
        return;
      }
      if (useBrowserViewer) {
        $("#pdfFrame" + frameId).attr("data", "data:application/pdf;base64," + data);
      } else {
        displayPdf(data, document.getElementById("canvas" + frameId), 1);
        if (frameId == "4") {
          displayPdf(data, document.getElementById("canvas4Page2"), 2);
        }
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        getReport(reportName, frameId);
      }, 60*1000);
    }).fail(function() { 
      console.log("Report not returned.");
      setTimeout(function() {
        getReport(reportName, frameId);
      }, 60*1000);
    });
  }

  function showReport(frameIdNum) {
    if (useBrowserViewer) {
      $(".pdfFrame").hide();
      $("#pdfFrame" + frameIdNum).show();
    } else {
      $(".pdfCanvas").hide();
      document.getElementById("canvas" + frameIdNum).style.display = 'block';
      if (frameIdNum == "4") {
        document.getElementById("canvas4Page2").style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
    
    $(".link").removeClass("active");
    $("#link" + frameIdNum).addClass("active");
  }
```